# Android Glide and Volley: Unable to display Images stored in Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-volley, android-glide, firebase-storage

I know the solution exists where people say that using the image caching tools like *Glide* or *Picasso*, you can display the images. But I have tried the same and it won't work.

Here is my implementation of uploading files to Firebase Storage

```
 if (uri != null) {
        //upload to storage
        StorageReference riversRef = imagesRef.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        UploadTask uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(uri);
        // Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Unable to process your request. Please try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
                if (downloadUrl != null) {
                    Date date = new Date();
                    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "IN");
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy /h:mm a", locale);
                    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("isXRead", String.valueOf(false));
                    map.put("isYRead", String.valueOf(true));
                    map.put("imgUrl", String.valueOf(downloadUrl));
                    map.put("timestamp", formattedDate);
                    map.put("user", "X");
                    ref.push().setValue(map);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The image gets uploaded well and returns the url, similar to

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/private.appspot.com/o/Messenger_images%2F14076?alt=media&token=2164ec58-55c2-4b03-b97a-ebfd36e66593
```

Here is how I'm trying to display the image using Volley:

```
ImageRequest ir = new ImageRequest(message.getImgUrl(), new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                // callback
                // new GlideOperations(context, img).glideMessenger(response);
                img.setImageBitmap(response);
            }
        }, 100, 100, null, null);
        //ir.setShouldCache(false);
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(ir);
```

Here is how I'm trying to display the image using Glide:

```
 try {
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(object)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .override(900, 400)
                .crossFade(100)
                .fitCenter()
                .error(R.drawable.wallpaper)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                        try {
                            mImageView.setImageDrawable(resource); 
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

None of the above seems to work. Appreciate any help.

**Solution**
Seems like I had problem with the `ImageView` I was using. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have quite a bit experience using Picasso and Firebase storage, I could help out if you're willing to give Picasso another try, Let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry but glide seems much more efficient

Comment: To load an image stored in Firebase Storage to an imageView using glide, I use `FirebaseImageLoader` class from [this thread's answer by Samuel](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/firebase-talk/IrJACH038DI), it works perfectly and you don't need to get the direct public URL of that image

Comment: @Wilik please assist me here http://stackoverflow.com/q/42480626/3671509

Answer (score 7):

The [`com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library includes the ability to load Firebase Storage images using Glide.

```
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
StorageReference storageReference = ...;

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = ...;

// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: please help me in this issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/42480626/3671509

Comment: .using is giving me an error.  Is there an updated version of this?