# How to download images with specific size from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am using firebase storage in my android app to store images uploaded by users. **all images uploaded are square in shape.**
I discovered that downloading this images consumes a lot of user bandwidth and i would like to reduce this consumption by reducing the size of image downloaded into a **square imageview**

I am using Glide to download this images and i have tried to download images of custom size but the image is not appearing on the imageview.

**interface**

```
public interface MyDataModel {
  public String buildUrl(int width, int height);
}
```

**my class which extends BaseGlideUrlLoader**

```
public class MyUrlLoader extends BaseGlideUrlLoader<MyDataModel> {
  public MyUrlLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  protected String getUrl(MyDataModel model, int width, int height) {
    // Construct the url for the correct size here.
    return model.buildUrl(width, height);
  }
}
```

**class which implements MyDataModel interface**

```
public class CustomImageSize implements MyDataModel {

  private String uri;

  public CustomImageSize(String uri){
    this.uri = uri;
  }

  @Override
  public String buildUrl(int width, int height) {

    return uri + "?w=" + width + "&h=" + height;
  }
}
```

**Finally**

```
CustomImageSize size = new CustomImageSize(uri);

  Glide.with(context)
    .using(new MyUrlLoader(context))
    .load(size)
    .centerCrop()
    .priority(Priority.HIGH)
    .into(imageView);
```

**RESULTS OF SOLUTION ABOVE**

Image is not appearing in my square imageview

**SOLUTION 2: use firebase image loader**

```
    // Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
StorageReference storageReference = ...;

ImageView imageView = ...;

// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

**RESULT OF SOLUTION 2 ABOVE**

**working! image is appearing BUT** it's like entire image is been downloaded which consume a lot of bandwidth. I just want a custom size image e.g 200px by 200px to be downloaded.

How can I do or change in my solution 1 above to download images of custom size from firebase storage?

**EDIT**

I have tried to access one of my images `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/....m.png` from the browser and it was loaded successfully to the webpage. but when i try to put to size specific parameters to my image url link `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/....m.png?w=100&h=100` an error appeared on the webpage

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that you can request for a specific size to an uploaded image in Firebase Storage by passing "w" and "h" GET request. Can you share the documentation or article that mentions this capability? I can't find it in the official documentation.

Comment: @Wilik find any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to download images from firebase storage using `MyUrlLoader` class

You see, firebase storage urls look like this

```
firebasestorage.googleapis.com/XXXX.appspot.com/Folder%2Image.png?&alt=media&token=XXX
```

As you can see above, the link already have this special question mark character `?` **which stands for the start of querying string** so when i use `CustomImageSize` class, another `?` was being added so the link was ending up with two `?` which made downloading to fail

```
firebasestorage.googleapis.com/XXXX.appspot.com/Folder%2Image.png?&alt=media&token=XXX?w=200&h=200
```

**Solution** was to remove the `?` in my `CustomImageSize` class. so it ended up like this

```
    public class CustomImageSize implements MyDataModel {

  private String uri;

  public CustomImageSize(String uri){
    this.uri = uri;
  }

  @Override
  public String buildUrl(int width, int height) {

    return uri + "w=" + width + "&h=" + height;
  }
}
```

**Although** it downloaded, am not sure whether entire image was being downloaded or just the custom size one. This is because, i tried to access the image in my browser after correcting the error that was making viewing to fail, but still **i was receiving an entire image. not a resized image (w=200&h=200)**

Comment: I think you can only download the same resource you have uploaded.  If you are worried about bandwidth, you can follow the cloud function example to create thumbnails and modify to your sizing needs.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events

Comment: As of now, this solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading your image using the following commands:-

```
StorageReference islandRef = storageRef.child("yourImage.jpg");
    // defines the specific size of your image
    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    islandRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            // Data for "yourImage.jpg" is returns, use this as needed
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is good but not efficient, `OutOfMemoryError` can be thrown which can lead to app clashing. i want lo load custom sized images efficiently using Glide

Comment: But in place of that ONE_MEGABYTE constant as 1024*1024, you can take less value as per your requirements.